# nil facebook_session with Facebooker gem and Rails 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebooker, tunnel

Integrating FB Connect into our site using Rails 2.2.2 and Facebooker gem (latest version). Login button, xd_receiver files generated fine to the point where the login popup window will open, I can log in, and it will then execute the onlogin event, but Facebooker's facebook_session method just keeps returning nil. Upon inspecting the session object, the various session cookies from FBC are definitely there and correct, so I'm presuming authentication was successful, but the nil facebook_session method is creating an impasse in development. What's worse, I have been noticing various discussions around needing to proxy or otherwise tunnel when developing locally (e.g. localhost:3000 won't work with the xd_receiver stuff). Any ideas?

Comment: Is the nil session happening on your local machine?  You do need to use an ssh tunnel to test fbconnect integration on your local machine.

Comment: Yes, it was the local machine. I ended up getting it sorted out by using dyndns and serving localhost over a public IP. Now I'm getting a different, even weirder error, but will open a separate question for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't calling `set_facebook_session` - doh!